# (*SKIP)(*FAIL) workaround in JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex pattern that works fine in regex101.com: `~<a .*?">(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bword\b`

I am trying to make it a Regexp so it can be used in the `replace()` function in JavaScript.

The line of JavaScript code is:

```js
var regex = new RegExp("~<a.*?\">(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\b"+ word + "\\b", 'g');
```

Where `word` is the word I'm trying to match.

When I run it though, the console shows the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
/~<a.*?">(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|word/: Nothing to repeat
```

Am I escaping characters wrong?

I tried backslash-escaping every special character I could find (`?`, `*`, `<` and so on) in my JavaScript code and it still spat out that error.

Comment: Did you select the ECMAScript flavor (on the left side) when you tested it on regex101?

Comment: @Ivar I see now, JavaScript doesn't have SKIP and FAIL control verbs for regex like Perl does. Then I need to figure out another way to write the pattern I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can work around the missing `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` support in JavaScript using capturing groups in the pattern and a bit of code logic.

Note the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verb sequence is explained in my YT video called ["Skipping matches in specific contexts (with SKIP & FAIL verbs)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvZ7knJVYW0). You can also find a demo of [JavaScript lookarounds](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/vg4Lohak/1/) for **four different scenarions: extracting, replacing, removing and splitting**.

Let's adjust the code for the current question. *Let's assume `word` always consists of word characters (digits, letters or underscores)*.

1. **Extracting**: Capture the word into Group 1 and only extract Group 1 values:

```js
const text = `foo <a href="foo.com">foo</a> foobar`;
const word = 'foo';
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`<a .*?">|\b(${word})\b`, 'gi');
console.log(Array.from(text.matchAll(regex), x=>x[1]).filter(Boolean)); // => 1st word and `>foo<`
```

2. **Removing**: Capture the context you need to keep into Group 1 and replace with a backreference to this group:

```js
const text = `foo <a href="foo.com">foo</a> foobar`;
const word = 'foo';
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`(<a .*?">)|\b${word}\b`, 'gi');
console.log(text.replace(regex, '$1')); // =>  <a href="foo.com"></a> foobar
```

3. **Replacing**: Capture the context you need to keep into Group 1 and when it is used, replace with Group 1 value, else, replace with what you need in a callback function/arrow function used as the replacement argument:

```js
const text = `foo <a href="foo.com">foo</a> foobar`;
const word = 'foo';
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`(<a .*?">)|\b${word}\b`, 'gi');
console.log(text.replace(regex, (match, group1) => group1 || 'buz' ));
// => buz <a href="foo.com">buz</a> foobar
```

4. **Splitting**: This is the most intricate scenario and it requires a bit more coding:

```js
const text = `foo <a href="foo.com">foo</a> foobar`;
const word = 'foo';
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`(<a .*?">)|\b${word}\b`, 'gi');

let m, res = [], offset = 0;
while (m = regex.exec(text)) { // If there is a match and...
  if (m[1] === undefined) {    // if Group 1 is not matched
    // put the substring to result array
    res.push(text.substring(offset, m.index)) // Put the value to array
    offset = m.index + m[0].length  // Set the new chunk start position
  }
}
if (offset < text.length) {     // If there is any more text after offset
  res.push(text.substr(offset)) // add it to the result array
}
console.log(res);
// => ["", " <a href=\"foo.com\">", "</a> foobar"]
```

Comment: The solution works nice thank you! I just wondering if there is an alternative to this without using `String.raw` because it's not supported for IE

Comment: @apaternina Sure, just make sure you escape backslashes correctly.